# Statistics circles in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, statistics

I would like to do something like this but I don't know how.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cTz7wTm.jpg]

I have an idea but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="stats">
    <div id="men" class="circle"></div>
    <div id="women" class="circle"></div>
    <div id="white-circle" class="small-circle"></div>
</div>

<style>
#stats {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #CCC;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

.circle#men {
   background: #27ae60; 
}

.circle#women {
   background: #f26646; 
}

.small-circle {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: white;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: if you want to do it by your self, you will have to use SVG (generate it with javascript), but there are alot of good chart libraries for javascript out there, you just have to search a bit

Comment: I provided a complete implementation in my answer, in case you're not comfortable writing one in SVG.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually called as donut chart. It will be difficult for you to just use a div tag. Instead use canvas or just use a javascript framework for charting. Here are few examples.

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

1. [Example1](http://jsfiddle.net/Kevin_Granger/R4h7A/)
2. [Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ENZD9/)
3. [Example3](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-doughnut-chart/)
4. [Example4](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-doughnut-chart/)

markup

```
<canvas width="500px" height="250px"></canvas>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var context = $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");

        var values = '24,43,43,45';
        var segments = values.split(",");
        var segmentColor = 50;
        var total = 0;

        //Reset the canvas
        context.restore();
        context.save();
        context.clearRect(0,0,500,250);

        for (i=0;i<segments.length;i++) {
            total = total + parseFloat(segments[i]);
        }

        var parts = 360/total;
        var startAngle=0

        context.translate(100,100)
        context.rotate(270*(Math.PI/180)); //Turn the chart around so the segments start from 12 o'clock

        for (i=0;i<segments.length;i++) {

            //Draw the segments
            context.fillStyle ="rgb(" + segmentColor + "," + segmentColor + "," + segmentColor + ")";
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0,0);
            context.arc(0,0,100,startAngle*(Math.PI/180),(startAngle + parseFloat(segments[i]*parts))*(Math.PI/180),false);
            context.lineTo(0,0);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();

            startAngle = startAngle + parseFloat(segments[i]*parts);
            segmentColor = segmentColor + 20;   
        }

            //Turn into a donut!!                   
            context.fillStyle = "White";
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(0,0,60,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();                 


});
```

Notice: var values = '24,43,43,45'; // This will basicall divide the circle into 4 parts
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgfb6/

Comment: This is basically just a link only answer, it would be better to include a sample of how to use `canvas` to meet the requirements

Comment: theoretically with creative use of 3d-transform and border radius and alot of divs you might be able to do it, but it wouldn't look as good and would be much more work, and it would probably be less compatible. is there any reason why you dont want svg?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to just use a chart framework which supports donut charts like [**d3js**](http://d3js.org/).

**Examples made with d3js**:

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193
- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3888852
- http://www.visualizing.org/visualizations/uk-olympic-sentiment-analysis

Comment: +1 I've used this in the past and it is excellent for representing statistical information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to make circles in css:

If you know how to make square in css you only need to add `border-radius: 100%` in css. That will convert a square into circle. Here is some more code which to address your question:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Disappering Circles </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#red {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100%
}
#blue{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
#yellow{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), and more specifically [highcharts-chart](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart) (*web-component of Highcharts*) to get a chart like this:

[image]

Implementation:

```js
chart.data = [{
  name: 'Clients',
  size: "100%",
  innerSize: "60%",
  showInLegend: true,
  dataLabels: {enabled: false},
  data: [
    {name: "Men", y: 2258, color: '#20ad61'},
    {name: "Women", y: 5023, color: '#f26645'},
  ],
}]

chart.legendOptions = {
  enabled: true,
  layout: 'vertical',
  align: 'right',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  labelFormatter: function() {return Math.round(this.y/7281*100)+"% "+this.name},
}

chart.chartOptions = {spacingLeft: 0,}

chart.highchartOptions = {
  title: {
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    y: -2
  },
  subtitle: {
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },
}
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 23em;
  height: 10em
}

#chart .highcharts-point {rx: initial; ry: initial}
```

```html
<base href="https://user-content-dot-custom-elements.appspot.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart/v2.0.1/highcharts-chart/">
<link rel="import" href="highcharts-chart.html">

<highcharts-chart id='chart' title='<b>7,281</b>' subtitle='CLIENTS' type="pie" title="" label="Gender" legend height-responsive></highcharts-chart>
```

**Note**: Click ***`Run Code Snippet`*** to see the chart.